# How to render a datatable cell with an object created at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

For someone who knows javascript well this is going to be a piece of cake. I want to put the wavesurfer object into the render function of my datatable. The render creates a div with id="demo" at runtime when I click on a button in my datatable.

**Render function of datatable**

```
"renderer": function ( api, rowIdx ) {
 ....
 return data ?
 $('<table/>').append( data ).prop('outerHTML') + $("<div></div>", {"id":"demo"}).prop('outerHTML') : false;
 }
```

**Audio Object which is going to fill the container with id="demo"**

```
var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer);
wavesurfer.init({
    container: document.querySelector('#demo'),
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple'
 });

wavesurfer.load('//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg');
```

When the page load I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Container element not found
```

Which happens because I have not clicked yet on the button which creates the div.

I want to be able to render the object for each row with a different file (.load)?
Could you please help me with this

Comment: We agree that the renderer function has to do with responsive layout, not child / details rows ...?

Comment: I am creating a jsfiddle which i will post soon. Yes this has to do with the responsive layout that in case the page is not able to handle all columns, some are hidden automatically and clicking a button on the row will show the hidden fields. When you click that will create a div child just below the row https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/

Comment: Just needed to be sure :) you dont have to create a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use a `.wawe` class instead of multiple `id`'s, and set the file `url` as an attribute on the element itself, ex `{"class":"wawe", url:"//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg"}` :

```
return data 
  ?  $('<table/>').append( data ).prop('outerHTML') + $("<div></div>", {"class":"wawe", url:"//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg"}).prop('outerHTML') 
  : false;
```

When a click on a row triggers a child row it immediately get the class `.parent`. So you can create a click handler on `.parent`, find the `.child` rows (always the next row) `.wawe` element and use the `url` attribute from that when you initialise WaveSurfer :

```
table.on('click', 'tr.parent', function() {
   var wavesurfer = Object.create(WaveSurfer),
       container = $(this).next('tr').find('.wawe')[0];
    wavesurfer.init({
      container: container,
      waveColor: 'violet',
      progressColor: 'purple'
   });
  wavesurfer.load(container.getAttribute('url'));
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/fxojLmvd/**

Hope this solves the problem. I didn't knew WaveSurfer before, thank you for that :)

Comment: ________SUPERSTAR_______

Comment: Just another question, why this does not render on mobile devices? iPhone in particular?

Comment: @QuentinTanioartino, what exactly does not render? I am not able to test this on a smartphone pt, are there any errors in a console?

Comment: well, not tested it yet, but if I open your jsfiddle from my mobile phone I cannot see anything, whereas, if I do the same from my laptop it works pretty well....